# AngularJS get nested json data in ui-router view

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I have an application with Miller Columns, i.e. a series of lists. Each column of this is a view.

The data is pulled in from a json file with a resolve in the route.

The first column displays a table of the top level data, e.g all the accounts in the data:

`_this.costAccounts = CostAccountsResolve;`

When a user clicks on a row, I load another route into the view for the second column, passing the account number:

`$state.go('miller.subaccount', { accountid: item.account_number });`

The route is:

```
.state('miller', {
    url: '/miller',
    resolve: {
      CostAccountsResolve: function (MockDataFactory) {
        return MockDataFactory.query({ filename: 'cost_accounts' });
      }
    },
    views: {
      ....
    }
  })

.state('miller.subaccount', {
    url: '/subaccount/:accountid',
    views: {
      'subaccounts@miller': {
        controller: 'SubaccountController as sub',
        templateUrl: 'modules/miller/templates/subaccounts.html'
      },
      'crud@miller': {}
    }
  })
```

So if the user clicks on account number 001 I go to a the subaccount state  with id 001: `/#/miller/subaccount/001`

This should display a table with the subaccounts of account 001. The data is in the format:

```
[
  {
    "account_number": "001",
    "account_name": "Account 1",
    "subaccounts": [
      {
        "account_number": "00101",
        "account_name": "SubAccount 1 of Account 1"
      },
      {
        "account_number": "00102",
        "account_name": "SubAccount 2 of Account 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "account_number": "002",
    "account_name": "Account 2",
    "subaccounts": [
      {
        "account_number": "00201",
        "account_name": "SubAccount 1 of Account 2"
      },
      {
        "account_number": "00202",
        "account_name": "SubAccount 2 of Account 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is still stored in the resolve, `CostAccountsResolve`.  So, how do I populate the table in the subaccounts view with the items in the `subaccounts` key for account 001?  In other words, I want 00101 and 00102 in the example json above.

Comment: Please explain _This is still stored in the resolve, `CostAccountsResolve`_  - I don't see any resolve in your state, are you asking about filtering the correct element from the accounts?

Comment: Sorry, the parent state has the resolve. I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Just to be sure - You need an example of getting the object with `account_number == "001"`? You can do it with [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=control)

Comment: Exactly, but how do I get the current ID to look for with it?

Comment: Please take a look at [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) - I think this is what you need to implement you requirement